# Is it possible to group error messages in validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, validationsummary

I have a validation summary on page.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="myValSumGroup" ID="myValSum" runat="server" />
```

And I have a few required validators which add to this summary:

```
A missing
B missing
N missing
```

But I have some (make it 10) additional required validators and all have the same error message

```
**SPECIAL is missing**
```

This add 10 more errors in summary. But as they have the same text is it possible to add to validation summary only:

```
**YOU HAVE ERRORS IN YOUR SPECIALS**
```

instead of

```
**SPECIAL is missing**
**SPECIAL is missing**
**SPECIAL is missing**
...
```

I have tried some JS voodoo magic but doesn't work:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="return Button2_onclick()" ...
<script type="text/javascript">
function Button2_onclick() {
    document.getElementById("<%=myValSum.ClientID %>").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("<%=myValSum.ClientID %>").innerHTML + 
            "<br>  YOU HAVE ERRORS IN YOUR SPECIALS";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this too, in you java-script function.

```
document.getElementById("<%=myValSum.ClientID %>").style.display="block";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to keep all validators(validator control like reqiredfieldvalidator) with **common** `ValidationGroup` which you will use in `Validationsummary` later.

Now,assign `ErrorMessage` property of every validator control to **blank** i.e."" or set Text property to * if you want to display it as mandatory.

At the end to display common error message of all validators,set `HeaderText` property of `ValidationSummary` to "YOU HAVE ERRORS IN YOUR SPECIALS".

You can use multiple ValidationSummary to group your errormessage based on `ValidationGroup` property

Comment: I don't want to add alert I am trying to add one message for multiple messages to validation summary control.

Comment: @1110 try this one.Earlier i was trying to achieve it with javascript with alert but let it be. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Please stop flagging this answer for moderator review. That's not what moderator flags are for.